# Sentence with two infinitives — "no right to try to change"

Tags: infinitive, subordinate-clause

I would like to translate this sentence into German:

> You have no right to try to change him.

In English, I have to use two infinitives in this sentence.

Since it is

> ich versuche, etw. zu machen

and the subordinate clause needs also a verb with "zu", I thought it might be something like

> Du hast kein Recht, ihn sich zu verändern zu versuchen.

But I feel that is possibly wrong. How could I build this kind of sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

German needs two infinitives as well here:

> Du hast kein Recht, ihn zu verändern zu versuchen.
>
> Du hast kein Recht, zu versuchen, ihn zu ändern.

Double infinitive does sound a bit weird, though, both in English and in German, the former a bit more than the latter.

So your sentence was basically OK, but the 'zu' stands alone - It doesn't merge with the verb.

Comment: and what about the type sich+akk+[ver]ändern? Shouldn't I put 'sich' somewhere in the sentence?

Comment: @VassilisDe Nope. *sich* makes the verb *reflexive* and thus changes the meaning to *change yourself*. Object and Subject are identical, then.

Comment: @VassilisDe A sentence where "sich" would make sense is: "Du hast kein Recht ihm einzureden, dass er sich zu ändern hat." (You have no right to talk him into thinking he had to change himself.)

Answer (score 2):

> Du hast kein Recht, zu versuchen, ihn zu verändern.

Note that the second verb should be "verändern" (or "ändern"), rather than the reflexive "sich verändern" or "sich ändern".

Comment: We love explanations!